# "brightway2" pkg incompatible on macOS Apple M1?

Tags: miniconda, installation-package, brightway

I've been trying to install the "brightway2" pkg in my virtual environment with the latest version of miniconda for macOS M1 chip (*Miniconda3 macOS Apple M1 64-bit bash*) by following carefully the procedure (https://2.docs.brightway.dev/installation.html) but  installation keeps failing due to conflicts.

When I insert this line
`conda install -y -q -c conda-forge -c cmutel brightway2 jupyterlab`

The command outputs the following

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: ...working... failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: ...working... 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package python_abi conflicts for:
brightway2 -> python_abi=3.9[build=*_cp39]
brightway2 -> bw2analyzer[version='<0.10.99'] -> python_abi[version='3.10.*|3.7.*|3.8.*',build='*_cp37m|*_cp310|*_cp38']
jupyterlab -> ipython -> python_abi[version='3.10.*|3.8.*|3.9.*',build='*_cp310|*_cp38|*_cp39']

Package wheel conflicts for:
jupyterlab -> jupyter-packaging[version='>=0.7,<1'] -> wheel
python=3.9 -> pip -> wheel

Package jinja2 conflicts for:
jupyterlab -> jupyter_server[version='>=1.4,<2'] -> jinja2[version='>2.10*|>=3.0.3']
jupyterlab -> jinja2[version='>=2.1|>=2.10']
```

I tried multiple times different versions of python, tried to install with anaconda, other miniconda versions and even pip command but nothing does it... I also made sure to update conda before creating my virtual environement with the following:

```
./conda update conda
```

Anybody would know if this is a macOS M1 incompatibility or is there any way around those conflicts?

Comment: Please don't post textual data as screenshots, post the console output as code-formatted text in your question.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I have edited my question following your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have added instructions for M1 Macs here: https://2.docs.brightway.dev/installation.html#installation-on-mac-m1

Comment: Thanks that works now, however there were some typos and omissions for the installation command lines to be complete. Here are that the commands that worked for me:
`CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 conda create -n bw_rosetta python=3.9`
`conda activate bw_rosetta`
`conda env config vars set CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64`
`conda config --append channels conda-forge`
`conda config --append channels cmutel`
`conda install brightway2 scikit-umfpack`
`conda remove pypardiso --force`

Comment: Thanks, the installation docs are updated.

Comment: Note that the corrections were for an older workaround, we now have a single package that does everything needed without emulation, forced package removal, env. variables, or other nonsense :)

Comment: Thank you Chris for making the experience always easier :)

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Brightway2 (and Python in general!). I have a MacBook Pro with an M1 Pro and I run through some problems when installing it. I followed the Brightway2 [step-by-step](https://2.docs.brightway.dev/installation.html#installation-on-mac-m1) guide for M1 Macs, and this is the error I kept having:

```
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: This system does not meet the minimum requirements for use of the Intel(R) Math Kernel Library. 
The processor must support the Intel(R) Supplemental Streaming SIMD Extensions 3 (Intel(R) SSSE3) instructions. 
The processor must support the Intel(R) Streaming SIMD Extensions 4.2 (Intel(R) SSE4.2) instructions. 
The processor must support the Intel(R) Advanced Vector Extensions (Intel(R) AVX) instructions
```

However, I managed to make it work following this post by [Alexb21](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18990465/alexb21) and his solution worked wonders for me:

> Thanks that works now, however there were some typos and omissions for the installation command lines to be complete. Here are that the commands that worked for me: CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 conda create -n bw_rosetta python=3.9 conda activate bw_rosetta conda env config vars set CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64 conda config --append channels conda-forge conda config --append channels cmutel conda install brightway2 scikit-umfpack conda remove pypardiso --force

At the end of his solution I also installed `jupyterlab` within the bw_rosetta environment, I tried installing `ipykernel` but it was not possible due to numerous conflicts.

I was wondering if this solution could be implemented/updated to the documentation for future M1 users.

Thank you to [Chris Mutel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164864/chris-mutel) and all people collaborating in this awesome project, and [Alexb21](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18990465/alexb21) for his solution!